# C#, implement 'static abstract' like methods

Tags: c#, static, abstract

I recently ran into a problem where it seems I need a 'static abstract' method. I know why it is impossible, but how can I work around this limitation?

For example I have an abstract class which has a description string. Since this string is common for all instances, it is marked as static, but I want to require that all classes derived from this class provide their own Description property so I marked it as abstract:

```
abstract class AbstractBase
{
    ...
    public static abstract string Description{get;}
    ...
}
```

It won't compile of course. I thought of using interfaces but interfaces may not contain static method signatures.

Should I make it simply non-static, and always get an instance to get that class specific information?

Any ideas?

Comment: Similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763344/c-virtual-or-abstract-static-methods/763364#763364

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I have abstract static methods in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284/why-cant-i-have-abstract-static-methods-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement virtual static properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346631/how-to-implement-virtual-static-properties)

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/66070907/6053778) I describe a pattern that can emulate the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining static and abstract is somewhat meaningless, yes. The idea behind static is one need not present an instance of the class in order to use the member in question; however with abstract, one expects an instance to be of a derived class that provides a concrete implementation.

I can see why you'd want this sort of combination, but the fact is the only effect would be to deny the implementation use of 'this' or any non-static members. That is, the parent class would dictate a restriction in the implementation of the derived class, even though there's no underlying difference between calling an abstract or 'static abstract' member (as both would need a concrete instance to figure out what implementation to use)

Comment: I thought the situation again, and I'm say that's true...
public abstract string {get;} impletented like public string {get {return "Izeeeeeeeeh";}} is enough class specific.

Comment: It's not meaningless.  Imagine that you're designing a framework.  You require that classes implementing ISomething expose some compile-time known data.  For example a "friendly class name".  You want the compiler to ensure that all ISomethings have this property.  If you want to do that now, then you have to use instance properties.  Which means creating an instance, instead of just querying the type.  That sucks.

Comment: I agree with @RyanBarrett, for framework design it can be useful to force a consumer to provide a function in a derived class, but also contractually state that the function is executed statically, without there being an instance.

Comment: One other way to go would be to allow an abstract base class to state that it must have a certain attribute defined on each child (again for providing compile time constant data)

Answer (score 34):

You can't.

The place to do this is with Attributes.

Eg

```
[Name("FooClass")]
class Foo
{
}
```

Comment: Indeed... one could have the public static Description property pick up the attribute value though to make it more accessible...

Comment: Would be interested to know how that works out at runtime. Does the attribute end up as an instance var somehow? I've read custom attributes before through reflection, but dont know how the CLR handles them

Comment: You can do a GetType on an object and get the list of custom attributes decorating that type via reflection. Each Custom Attribute can have its own state that it can expose via properties.

Comment: Wouldn't reflecting like that be expensive?

Comment: I know this is a really old question/answer but how can you make sure you get a compile error if inheriting classes don't have that attribute?

Comment: @Davy8: That probably isn't possible, but you could always write a unit test to assert that all subtypes of `Foo` have a `NameAttribute` applied.

Comment: I know this answer is really old, but with .NET 6, static abstract members have been introduced for interfaces :D

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind deferring to implementations to sensibly implement the Description property, you can simply do

```
public abstract string ClassDescription {get; } 
// ClassDescription is more intention-revealing than Description
```

And implementing classes would do something like this:

```
static string classDescription="My Description for this class";
override string  ClassDescription { get { return classDescription; } }
```

Then, your classes are required to follow the contract of having a description, but you leave it to them to do it sensibly. There's no way of specifying an implementation in an object-oriented fashion (except through cruel, fragile hacks).

However, in my mind this Description is class metadata, so I would prefer to use the attribute mechanism as others have described. If you are particularly worried about multiple uses of reflection, create an object which reflects over the attribute that you're concerned with, and store a dictionary between the Type and the Description. That will minimize the reflection (other than run time type inspection, which isn't all that bad). The dictionary can be stored as a member of whatever class that typically needs this information, or, if clients across the domain require it, via a singleton or context object.

Answer (score 5):

If it is static, there is only one instance of the variable, I don't see how inheritance would make sense if we could do what you want to accomplish with static vars in derived classes. Personally I think you are going to far to try to avoid a instance var.

Why not just the classic way?

```
abstract class AbstractBase
{
    protected string _Description = "I am boring abstract default value";
}

class Foo : AbstractBase {

     public Foo() {
       _Description = "I am foo!";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A possible workaround is to define a Singleton of your derived class in your base class with the help of Generics.

```
import System;

public abstract class AbstractBase<T>
    where T : AbstractBase<T>, new()
{
    private static T _instance = new T();

    public abstract string Description { get; }
    public static string GetDescription()
    {
        return _instance.Description;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : AbstractBase<DerivedClass>
{
    public override string Description => "This is the derived Class";
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DerivedClass.GetDescription());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The trick is to tell your `AbstractBase<T>` some details about how  `DerivedClass` is implemented:

- It is newable with `where T: new()` so it can create a Singleton instance
- It derives from itself with `where T : AbstractBase<T>` so it knows that there will be a implementation of `Description`

This way `_instance` contains the `Description` field which can be called in the static Method `GetDescription()`.
This forces you to overwrite `Description`in your `DerivedClass` and allows you to call its value with `DerivedClass.GetDescription()`

Answer (score 3):

It's not static if it has to be called on an instance.

If you're not calling it on an instance, then there's no polymorphism at play (i.e. ChildA.Description is completely unrelated to ChildB.Description as far as the language is concerned).

Answer (score 1):

You can...

In the abstract class...

```
 protected abstract InWindow WindowInstance { get; set; }
```

In the derived class...

```
    private static InWindow _instance;


    protected override InWindow WindowInstance
    {
        get => _instance;
        set => _instance = value;
    }
```

Comment: This should be the closest you can get. Just wrap your static field with a non-static property.

Comment: Don't change the value of a static field from a non-static method/property!

Answer (score 0):

You could make the "abstract" base method throw an `Exception`, so then a developer is "warned" if he tries to invoke this method on a child class without overriding.

The downside is that one might extend the class and not use this method. Then refer to other answers provided.