# PHP Strict standards: what's wrong with this code?

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class, php-5.3, factory-method

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does PHP 5.2+ disallow abstract static class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999066/why-does-php-5-2-disallow-abstract-static-class-methods)
>   [Why can't you call abstract functions from abstract classes in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859633/why-cant-you-call-abstract-functions-from-abstract-classes-in-php)

I'm running this code on **PHP 5.3.8**:

```
abstract class Geometry
{
    abstract public static function fromArray(array $array);
}

class Point extends Geometry
{
    public static function fromArray(array $point)
    {
        return new self($point[0], $point[1]);
    }
}
```

And receive the following error:

> Strict Standards:  Static function Geometry::fromArray() should not be abstract

- What's wrong with this approach?
- Any viable alternative to force concrete classes to implement this factory method?

Comment: @ajreal: `return new static` doesn't address the issue, and is not the desired behavior (I want to return a new `Point`, not a new `Geometry`)

Comment: @ajreal: similar issue, but I don't face the same use case and my code doesn't trigger the *fatal error* this user faces. My request is specifically targeted at the Strict Standards warning.

Comment: return without the `new`

Comment: @ajreal: `return static($point[0], $point[1])` => Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Comment: @rdlowrey: same question, but different goal: we can reasonably argue that he "should redesign things so getSelectSQL() is an abstract /instance/ method" as a commentator says, however my aim is to force a concrete class to provide a **factory method**, which is by definition, **static**. So I'd be happy to have an answer at least to my second question: "any viable alternative to force concrete classes to implement this factory method?"

Comment: Interesting reading: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you make Geometry an interface, and have Point implement it?

Comment: My goal was to implement the [OpenGIS model](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/opengis-geometry-model.html), and I do have some common behavior in the `Geometry` class, thus I have to introduce an interface just to remove the Strict Standards error: `class Geometry implements IGeometry` (even though the code worked fine if we ignore the warning). That said, I think your solution is the only one I've left!

Comment: Glad that works for you. I'm not such an expert as to be certain this is a deliberate behaviour - would it be worth trying on 5.4 to see if the same warning results?

Comment: *very* interesting indeed, I just tried with the latest build of PHP (5.4.0RC3-dev), and no E_STRICT error is raised for this code! Did they make another 180° turn?

Comment: If it isn't covered by the ticket above, suggest you raise another. And require PHP 5.4+ for your application ;-)