# PHPunit mockobject abstract and static method

Tags: php, static, phpunit, mocking, abstract

I would like to test a method from an abstract class. In this class is there a abstract method with is static.

I use PHPUnit. With normal abstract methods it works:

```
<?php
abstract class AbstractClass
{
  public function concreteMethod()
  {
    return $this->abstractMethod();
  }

  public abstract function abstractMethod();
}

class AbstractClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testConcreteMethod()
  {
    $stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('AbstractClass');
    $stub->expects($this->any())
         ->method('abstractMethod')
         ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));

    $this->assertTrue($stub->concreteMethod());
  }
}
?>
```

phpunit file.php works.

But if the abstractMethod is static it displays:

PHP Fatal error:  Class Mock_AbstractClass_6332ae11 contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (AbstractClass::abstractMethod) in /usr/local/apache2/php5.3/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php(1135) : eval()'d code on line 33

Answer (score 3):

You can't have abstract static methods. It will generate an E_STRICT message in PHP.

Devise an alternative strategy for your class implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.3 is it possible to have abstract static methods, discussed here: 
[Why does PHP 5.2+ disallow abstract static class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999066/why-does-php-5-2-disallow-abstract-static-class-methods)

With phpunit 3.5beta  the following works:

```
<?php

class AbstractClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testConcreteMethod()
  {
    $stub = new myStub;
    $this->assertTrue($stub->concreteMethod());
  }
}


abstract class AbstractClass
{
  public function concreteMethod()
  {
    return static::abstractMethod();
  }

  public static abstract function abstractMethod();
}

class myStub extends AbstractClass {
    public static function abstractMethod() {
        return true;
    }
}

?>
```

> PHPUnit 3.5.0beta1 by Sebastian
>   Bergmann.
>
> .

Note that you need to use "static::" not "self::" as of the whole late static binding issue.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php