# How to test a static method of abstract class with phpunit in PHP

Tags: php, function, static, phpunit, abstract

I need to mock static method of class. But in phpunit:4 and later versions mocking static method is impossible (I get exception with message 'Static method "findBy" cannot be invoked on mock object'). How i need configure mock to get successful test?

I tried create mock class without phphunit manually. Somethig like `tests/Mocks/MyClass.php` that extends abstract class and implement my static method/

```php
interface IdentityInterface
{
     // this method calling first in other component
    public static function findBy(string $number, ?string $trunk): ?IdentityInterface;
}

abstract class Identity implements IdentityInterface
{
    // this method and other calling after findBy method
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name; // need to cover
    }
}
```

My static method must return instance of itself to use other internal methods that i need to cover.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPunit mockobject abstract and static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247408/phpunit-mockobject-abstract-and-static-method)

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI My method is not abstract and i can not create SomeIdentity class that extends Identity, because it is not provided for by the package structure. And also phpunit:3.5 is deprecated and i can not to use it for test static methods