# PHP: polymorphic abstract static methods

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, abstract, static-polymorphism

I'm trying to do something like this but i don't succeed.

```
abstract class Animal 
{ 
    abstract static function getName();
    static function sayName() { echo self::getName(); }
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You have two problems:

1. static functions can't be abstact in php anymore.
2. As said before, late static binding: as method getName() is defined in child class, you need to access it with static::getName() instead of self::getName()

Comment: Point 1 is no longer true now - static function can now be abstract again starting from PHP 7.0 - however `self::getName()` needed to change to `static::getName()` in order for it to work.

RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/reclassify_e_strict#abstract_static_methods

Answer (score 6):

It would have been nice if you'd have given a hint as to **how** you "don't succeed", but I suppose you're stumbling across static bindings and need to use [*late static bindings*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) introduced in PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is maybe you are trying to instantiate an object from that class.

You **can't**. It is an `abstract` class. Subclass it, and then instantiate that.

Answer (score 1):

That will not succeed- you cannot have an abstract static function. See the accepted answer [Why does PHP 5.2+ disallow abstract static class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999066/why-does-php-5-2-disallow-abstract-static-class-methods) for details on why.