# I can't use a static method, but that seems to be reasonable

Tags: php, object, inheritance, static

base class:

```
abstract class Challenge
{
    abstract **static** public function getName();
}
```

now two classes from it:

```
class ChallengeType1 extends Challenge
{
    public **static** function getName()
    {
        return 'Swimming';
    }
}

class ChallengeType2 extends Challenge
{
    public **static** function getName()
    {
        return 'Climbing';
    }
}
```

as you all might know, we can't use `static`, but it would be reasonable. So I can't do like that: for example, I have the classname, so I want to know it's name: `ChallengeType2::getName();` - it will fail! First I should construct the object - looks unnecessary (not to mention, what it this class have very complex initialization?)

Comment: The code you've posted works fine from where I'm standing.  Well, once the asterisks are removed.

Comment: Please don't decorate your code with things like `**static**`. The code you post should be *valid* code.

Comment: What makes you think this doesn't work? What error are you getting? Give us enough information to help you, and you'll get better results and fewer downvotes.

Comment: oh, if I add the static keyword, php 5.4 will say: Static function Challenge::getName() should not be abstract in

Comment: Your code looks fine - Are you running this from command-line or via a dev-tool (i.e. Eclipse, etc)?  And are you sure you are using 5.4 ?

Comment: yes. This is 5.4.6. And for the line "abstract static public function getName();" it will say "Strict Standards: Static function Challenge::getName() should not be abstract in sklsdkf"

Comment: I was mistaken, it actually didn't work in my IDE but it showed me an empty `stdout` which is what I expected - Once I checked my `stderr` console, the error you posted was there.  I've researched it and presented a solution below.

Comment: @user893856, please have a look at my answer below and let me know if my solution works for you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you cannot have `static abstract` methods on an `abstract class`. See here:

[Why does PHP 5.2+ disallow abstract static class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999066/why-does-php-5-2-disallow-abstract-static-class-methods)

But you can declare an `interface` to require a `static` method.

Here is an example that compiles:

**Working Example**

```
<?php
interface IChallenge
{
    static function getName();
}

abstract class Challenge implements IChallenge
{

}

class ChallengeType1 extends Challenge
{
    public static function getName()
    {
        return 'Swimming';
    }
}

class ChallengeType2 extends Challenge
{
    public static function getName()
    {
        return 'Climbing';
    }
}
```