# PHP: Abstract Static Function Best Practice

Tags: php, inheritance, static, abstract

[So you can't make an abstract static function in php.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999066/why-does-php-5-2-disallow-abstract-static-class-methods)

The alternatives as I see them are to:

1. Make the function non-static and write extra boilerplate code to create and store the object so I can access that function.

   ```
   abstract class Foo {

     abstract public function bar();

   }

   abstract class Good {

     public function bar() {
       ...
     }

   }

   // boilerplate to access Good->bar()... potentially a lot in multiple files
   $g = new Good();
   $g->bar();
   ```
2. Fill in the static function in my abstract class with a [BadMethodCallException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php), so that any call to a child class which doesn't implement it will throw the exception.

   ```
   abstract class Foo {

     public static function bar() {
       throw new BadMethodCallException("Not Implemented By Child Class :(");
     }

   }

   class Good extends Foo {

     public static function bar() {
       // ...
     }

   }

   class Bad extends Foo {

     // no bar implementation

   }

   Good::bar(); // works
   Bad::bar():  // exception
   ```

I'm leaning towards 2. but was wondering if there's any community consensus on this issue or best practices.

Comment: How would you imagine calling your static abstract method? Perhaps if you explain how you'd like to call the function we can propose a solution.

Comment: I'd like to implement the static abstract method in a child class, then call that.  For example: `Good::bar()`.

Comment: If you're going to know the class you're using that makes an abstract stub useless for it, since it's not required for the abstract, only for the actual class.

Comment: Yes and no.  I find it useful as a reminder to implement that function across all child classes- it's my way of noting that you should have this function available.  In the program itself it may not be used, but it is still helpful while writing the code.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making an interface with a static function, then implementing the interface in the abstract class.  This forces the child classes to define the method, which is basically what I wanted with an abstract static function.

```
interface ModelFactoryInterface {
  public static function offer();
}

abstract class ModelHelper implements ModelFactoryInterface {

  protected $tester;

  public function __construct($tester) {
    $this->tester = $tester;
  }

}

/* Location
 * ------------------------------------------------------ */
final class LocationHelper extends ModelHelper {

  public static function offer() {
    return new Location(...)
  }

}
```