# php - laravel - should not be abstract

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a public version of my website going.
I can connect to the page. routing is working.

The app is working with an API, and that is giving errors:

```
ErrorException in Transformer.php line 16:
Runtime Notice: Static function App\Transformers\Transformer::transform() should not be abstract
```

The transformer get's called like this:
`FeedTransformer::transformCollection( $userFeed )`
and this is build up like following:

FeedTransformer.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Transformers;

use App\Story;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FeedTransformer extends Transformer {

  public static function transform(Model $item, $args = [ ]) {
    $return = array();

    if ($item instanceof Story) {
      $return = StoryTransformer::transform( $item, [ 'level' => 'story' ] );
    }
    if ($item instanceof Post) {
      $return = PostTransformer::transform( $item, [ 'level' => 'posts' ] );
    }

    return $return;
  }
}
```

and the Transformer.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Transformers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class Transformer {
  public static function transformCollection($items, $args = []) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      array_push( $var, static::transform( $item , $args) );
    }
    return $var;
  }

  public static abstract function transform(Model $item,$args = []);
}
```

So I'm not fully sure why this is causing an error on my server while not on my localhost development

Anyone got a clue why this error is being thrown?

Comment: Change `public static abstract function` to `public abstract function` Maybe the difference is the error_reporing setting.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999066/why-does-php-5-2-disallow-abstract-static-class-methods

Comment: @lolka_bolka why would i remove the static part?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, remove abstract not static.

Answer (score 0):

A static function can be called without creating an instance of the object, so declaring a static method as abstract is not supposed to happen.

You can use [Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.interfaces.php) if you want to declare which methods a class has to implements.

**EDIT:** otherwise, you have to declare your class without the `Abstract` word.

Comment: It's not for declaring what methods they should have, it's for having a method availible in all it's subclasses without having to recode it everytime. it works on my local dev version.

Comment: so you simply should remove the `Abstract` keyword in front of your class declaration, and move all the abstract things into an interface (for