# How can i enforce an extending class to have a static method?

Tags: php, oop, abstraction

I basically want class B to implement a method that's been defined in class A. However when i do so i get the following error.

> **Strict Standards**: Static function A::test() should not be abstract in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.php on line 4

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_STRICT );

abstract class A{
    public abstract static function test();
}

class B extends A {
    public  static function test(){
        echo 'Testing';
    };
}

echo B::test();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods are not part of the object, so they shouldn't  be extended.

Make the method concrete.

I actually struggled with this same problem once I started building unit tests (I almost religiously avoid static methods now, but that's a whole side conversation).  Check out this question for someone answering your question berr than I can: [Why does PHP 5.2+ disallow abstract static class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999066/why-does-php-5-2-disallow-abstract-static-class-methods)

Comment: Could you be more clear ? I definitely want class B to have the method test(). How can i enforce that from class A ?

Comment: I updated my answer to be a bit more helpful.  But you should really just make the method not-static if you want it to be a part of your class hierarchy.