# How to get value of abstract "const" property using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, introspection

I've got a class defined like this:

```
public abstract class Uniform<T>
{
    public abstract string GlslType { get; }
    ...
}
```

And then a subclass defined like this:

```
public class UniformInt : Uniform<int>
{
    public override string GlslType
    {
        get { return "int"; }
    }
}
```

And then a method somewhere else that looks like this:

```
    public static string GetCode<T>()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var type = typeof(T);
        sb.AppendFormat("struct {0} {{\n", type.Name);
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach(var f in fields)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("    {0} {1};\n", f.FieldType.GetProperty("GlslType").GetValue(???), f.Name);
        }
        ...
    }
```

I'm having trouble filling in the `???`s. I believe `GetValue` expects an instance of the object, but I don't really care what instance it is because they all return the same value. And AFAIK there's no such thing as a `public abstract static readonly` value, so I have to use properties.

So what can I put in place of those `???`s to get back "int" (assuming one the fields was a `UniformInt`).

As a side: How can I limit `fields` to only field types that inherit `Uniform<>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since your property is not static the compiler doesn't know that they all return the same value. Since your `UniformInt` is not sealed, another user could inherit from it and override `GlslType` to return something else. Then `UniformInt` and all derived classes could be used for your `GetCode<T>()` method.

A static method would really be the best option. To make sure that you implement them on all classes (something you can't force because static methods can't be abstract) I would write a simple unit test that uses reflection to load all classes that inherit from `Uniform<T>` and check if they have the static property defined.

UPDATE

When thinking about how Attributes could help and after some experimenting I came up with the following. It definitely won't win a beauty contest but as a learning exercise it was helpful ;)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    internal class StackOverflowTest
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            string sInt = UniformInt.GlslType;
            string sDouble = UniformDouble.GlslType;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Uniform<B, T> // Curiously recurring template pattern 
        where B : Uniform<B, T>
    {
        public static string GlslType
        {
            get
            {
                var attribute = typeof(B).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GlslTypeAttribute), true);

                if (!attribute.Any())
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        "The GslType cannot be determined. Make sure the GslTypeAttribute is added to all derived classes.");
                }

                return ((GlslTypeAttribute)attribute[0]).GlslType;
            }
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    internal sealed class GlslTypeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string GlslType { get; private set; }

        public GlslTypeAttribute(string glslType)
        {
            GlslType = glslType;
        }
    }

    [GlslType("int")]
    public class UniformInt : Uniform<UniformInt, int> // Curiously recurring template pattern 
    {
    }

    [GlslType("double")]
    public class UniformDouble : Uniform<UniformDouble, double> // Curiously recurring template pattern 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah -- `public class UniformInt : Uniform<UniformInt, int>` -- doesn't that create a circular reference?

Comment: @Mark Nope :) It's even a pattern: Curiously recurring template pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) The code can be run as a console application without any problems

Answer (score 2):

You need an instance of `UniformInt` in order to get the value of a non-static property:

```
UniformInt someUniformInt = ...
f.FieldType.GetProperty("GlslType").GetValue(someUniformInt, null)
```

> As a side: How can I limit fields to only field types that inherit Uniform?

```
bool isDerivesFromUniformOfInt = typeof(Uniform<int>)
    .IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType);
```

or if you don't know the type of `T` in advance:

```
bool isDerivesFromUniformOfT = typeof(Uniform<>)
    .MakeGenericType(typeof(T))
    .IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType);
```

Comment: There's no other way? I don't really want instantiate one using their existing constructors because it would have ill effects.... I'd have to write an `internal` constructor I think, but then I'd have to add said secret constructor to *every* subclass of `Uniform<T>` just so that I can obtain the value of `GlslType`?

Comment: @Mark, think logically: you want to get the value of a non-static property. Without an instance of a type? This has strictly nothing to do with any reflection or whatever. Its simple and basic OOP rule. You can only get values of static properties without needing an instance of the containing class.

Comment: I meant if we change `GlslType` to something else that can be obtained more easily. That's not set in stone.

Comment: The aside bit... I guess I shouldn't have wrote `Uniform<T>` because I didn't mean the same `T` used to call `GetCode<T>`.. I meant the generic `Uniform<>`. `type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(f => typeof(Uniform<>).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))` doesn't return anything... I'm thinking because `Uniform<>` is abstract... nothing is assignable from it?

Comment: @Mark, no, it's because `f.FieldType` is a closed generic type. So you need to specify the generic argument as explained in mu answer: `typeof(Uniform<>).MakeGenericType(SomeType).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType)`. It's normal that `typeof(Uniform<>).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType)` returns false. `f.FieldType` doesn't derive from `Uniform<>`. It derives from `Uniform<SomeType>` which is what it is assignable from.

Comment: Well then what do I fill in for `SomeType`? I don't know what `SomeType` is beforehand, and it isn't `T`.

Comment: @Mark, in this case you could use the BaseType: `typeof(Uniform<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(f.FieldType).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())`. Be careful though as if BaseType is not generic type, calling `GetGenericTypeDefinition` might throw. To test whether it is a generic type you could test the `IsGenericType` property first.

Comment: You've got an extra `typeof()` in there, but from what I gather, I should do this: `var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(f => f.FieldType.BaseType.IsGenericType && typeof(Uniform<>).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()));`. *That* seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark, indeed. I made an error. No need of typeof around f.FieldType.

Answer (score 1):

The `GlslType` is not static, so you need an object reference before you can access it's value. The subject of static properties in abstract classes has been covered extensively already, ie:

- [C#, implement 'static abstract' like methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823665/c-implement-static-abstract-like-methods)
- [Can't define static abstract string property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567569/cant-define-static-abstract-string-property)

Comment: From these I've gathered 3 possible solutions: (1) use a static method as Wouter suggests, (2) use a static property in the base class to guarantee it's existence, then override with "new" in derived classes, (3) use a class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

Add static methods to all derived classes that return the `GlslType`. Nothing *needs* to be added to the base class. Can use unit testing + reflection to check for missing implementation. Suggested by [Wouter de Kort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8799945/65387).

## Solution 2

Change `Uniform<T>` to make `GlslType` static:

```
public abstract class Uniform<T>
{
    public static string GlslType { get { throw new NotImplementedException("Please override with \"new\" in derived class."); } }
    ...
}
```

Change `UniformInt` to "override" `GlslType`, keeping the static modifier:

```
public class UniformInt : Uniform<int>
{
    public new static string GlslType
    {
        get { return "int"; }
    }
}
```

Fill `???` with `null, null`:

```
sb.AppendFormat("    {0} {1};\n", f.FieldType.GetProperty("GlslType").GetValue(null,null), f.Name);
```

## Solution 3

Use [attributes instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/823673/65387). Something like:

```
[GlslType("int")]
public class UniformInt : Uniform<int>
{
}
```

### Conclusion

All 3 of these solutions are pretty similar and seem to have the same drawbacks (can't enforce derived class to implement it). Throwing an exception via method 1 or 2 will help find errors quickly, or with 3 I can just skip over classes that don't have the attribute by modifying my `fields` condition.